# How to catch a non-numerical value?

Tags: java

I'm having problem with the try & catch. The requirement is that it has to be inside a do while loop. It has to catch non-numerical values (for simplicity I'm trying to catch non-double values). The programme runs fine when numbers are entered, but when I enter a letter it doesn't display the desired "No number" message. The code is as follows:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Triangle {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException
        {

            // inputting a new scanner
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            double a=0; double b=0; double c=0;
            do {   
                try{
                    // prompt the user to enter values
                    System.out.println("Enter values for triangle sides a, b and c"
                    + "\n(only numbers are accepted): ");
                    a=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
                    b=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
                    c=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    System.out.println("Not a number");
                    }

                if (a == (double)a && b == (double)b && c == (double)c)
                    System.out.println("\nThe values you have entered are:\na = " + a +
                    "\nb = " + b + "\nc = " + c);

                boolean sumGreater = isTriangle(a, b, c); // invoking method isTriangle

                // if statement to check if entered values form triangle or not
                if (!sumGreater)

                    // Display message if statement is false
                    System.out.println("The entered values do not form a triangle");

                else
                    // Display output if message is true.
                    // Methods triangleType,
                    // perimeter and area, are invoked inside the output.
                    System.out.printf("\nThe type of triangle is: %s" + "\nPerimeter = %.2f" + "\nArea = %.2f \n", triangleType(a,b,c), perimeter(a,b,c), area(a,b,c));

            } while (a==(double)a && b==(double)b && c==(double)c);
        }

        // Defining method isTriangle as boolean
        public static boolean isTriangle(double a, double b, double c) {
            boolean sumGreater; // declaring expression as a boolean

            // if statement to check if the entered values form a triangle,
            // using the triangle inequality theorem, where sum of any two sides
            // must be greater the the remaining third side
            if((a+b)>c && (a+c)>b && (b+c)>a)
                sumGreater = true;
            else
                sumGreater = false;
            return sumGreater; // returning the value to main method
        }

        // Defining method perimeter as double
        public static double perimeter(double a, double b, double c) {
            double perimeter = a+b+c; // declaring the sum of the values as double
            return perimeter; // returning the value of perimeter to main method
        }

        // Defining method area as double, using Heron's formula to calculate area
        public static double area(double a, double b, double c) {
            double s=(a+b+c)/2;
            double h=s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c);
            double area = Math.sqrt(h);
            return area; // returnig the value of area to main method
        }

        // Defining method triangleType as String, to determine type of triangle
        public static String triangleType(double a, double b, double c) {
            String triangleType = " ";

            // if statement to determine type of triangle
            if (a==b&&a==c&&b==c)
                triangleType = "Equilateral";
            else if(a==b||b==c||a==c)
                triangleType = "Isosceles";
            else
                triangleType = "Scalene";
            return triangleType; // returning value of triangleType to main method
        }
    }
```

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: "Here I have a very long class, with one error" ... "Better post the whole class, people will like it". Good thinking

Comment: I would change `if (sumGreater==false)` to `if (!sumGreater)`

Comment: Thanks, I thought showing the whole thing would help understanding. Still when i type in a letter, instead the message "Not a number" i get several lines in red text informing me of some mistake with the MisMatchexception

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error after the line

```
} while (a==(double)a && b==(double)b && c==(double)c);
```

Put a `}` after this line. Your program seems to run for me.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. Still when I run the programme and type a letter, I don't get the needed response, which should be "Not a number". Instead I get lots of lines in red text, informing me of some mistake

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to define a method (`isTriangle()`) inside another method (`main()`). You can't do that in Java. All methods must be inside the class.

Moreover, you shouldn't try to use a, b and c if they're not valid doubles. So, instead of doing

```
try {
    // prompt the user to enter values
    System.out.println("Enter values for triangle sides a, b and c"
                 + "\n(only numbers are accepted): ");
    a=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
    b=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
    c=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("Not a number");
}

// use a, b and c, although they were not entered correctly
```

you should do

```
try {
    // prompt the user to enter values
    System.out.println("Enter values for triangle sides a, b and c"
                + "\n(only numbers are accepted): ");
    a=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
    b=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
    c=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double

    // use a, b and c: you're sure they have been entered correctly
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("Not a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below code, it is suitable for your requirement. There is } is missing after while please add.

```
            try{
                // prompt the user to enter values
                System.out.println("Enter values for triangle sides a, b and c"
                + "\n(only numbers are accepted): \t");
                a=Double.parseDouble(input.next());
                b=Double.parseDouble(input.next());
                c=Double.parseDouble(input.next());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println(" Not a number");
                continue;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, all fine and working when entering numerical values. But When I enter a letter I get this message:       `Exception in thread  "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
 at Triangle.main(Triangle.java:31)
Java Result: 1` I want the mesagge "Not a mumber" to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You're catching the wrong type of exception, and the error message you got tells you that. The `Scanner.nextDouble()` method throws `InputMismatchException` when the token (in this case - the text from your input) is not a float number. The `NumberFormatException` is thrown by `Double.parseDouble()` method, not by Scanner.

As a general advice, you should read the Javadoc documentation of the method you use, as it clearly explains the kind of results and exceptions you can encounter when invoking it. Catching the exceptions will not always be forced by the compiler, like in this case - the `java.util.InputMismatchException` is a `RuntimeException`, i.e. not a checked exception so it's not obligatory to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the suggestions, finally managed to write the code that gives me the desired result according to input:

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Triangle {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    // inputting a new scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double a=0; double b=0; double c=0; // declaring and initializing doubles

    // starting do-while loop
    do {

        // using try-catch method to catch mistakenly entered values
        try{
            // prompt the user to enter values
            System.out.println("Enter values for triangle sides a, b and c"
            + "\n(only numbers are accepted): ");
            a=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
            b=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
            c=input.nextDouble(); // inputing and declaring value as double
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {

            // display message if entered value isn't a number
            System.out.println("Not a number");
            }
    } while (a!=(double)a && b!=(double)b && c!=(double)c); // end of do-while loop

        // displaying entered values, while avoiding to display the initialized 
        if (a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0)
            System.out.println("\nThe values you have entered are:\na = " + a +
                    "\nb = " + b + "\nc = " + c);

        boolean sumGreater = isTriangle(a, b, c); // invoking method isTriangle

        // if statement to check if entered values form triangle or not,
        // while avoiding the initialized values to be displayed
        if (!sumGreater && a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0)

            // Display message if statement is false
            System.out.println("The entered values do not form a triangle");

        else if(a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0)
            // Display output if message is true.
            // Methods triangleType,
            // perimeter and area, are invoked inside the output.
            System.out.printf("\nThe type of triangle is: %s" + 
                    "\nPerimeter = %.2f" + "\nArea = %.2f \n", 
                    triangleType(a,b,c), perimeter(a,b,c), area(a,b,c));
}

// Defining method isTriangle as boolean
public static boolean isTriangle(double a, double b, double c) {
    boolean sumGreater; // declaring expression as a boolean

    // if statement to check if the entered values form a triangle,
    // using the triangle inequality theorem, where sum of any two sides
    // must be greater the the remaining third side
    if((a+b)>c && (a+c)>b && (b+c)>a)
        sumGreater = true;
    else
        sumGreater = false;
    return sumGreater; // returning the value to main method
}

// Defining method perimeter as double
public static double perimeter(double a, double b, double c) {
    double perimeter = a+b+c; // declaring the sum of the values as double
    return perimeter; // returning the value of perimeter to main method
}

// Defining method area as double, using Heron's formula to calculate area
public static double area(double a, double b, double c) {
    double s=(a+b+c)/2;
    double h=s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c);
    double area = Math.sqrt(h);
    return area; // returnig the value of area to main method
}

// Defining method triangleType as String, to determine type of triangle
public static String triangleType(double a, double b, double c) {
    String triangleType = " ";

    // if statement to determine type of triangle depending on met conditions
    if (a==b&&a==c&&b==c)
        triangleType = "Equilateral";
    else if(a==b||b==c||a==c)
        triangleType = "Isosceles";
    else
        triangleType = "Scalene";
    return triangleType; // returning value of triangleType to main method
}
```

}